# python pyqt wider window than screen width

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I tried to set window dimensions with `self.resize(1450,250)` more than is my screen resolution (1280, 800). But it limits window width to max 1280.

How can I set window width wider than my screen width?

my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork, QtWebKit

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)

        self.setGeometry(3,30,800,800) # Position window
        self.resize(1450,250)  # Resize window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    programwindow = MainWindow()
    programwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to give more information - e.g I have no idea what `self.resize` refers to (presumably a method from some GUI framework?)

Comment: sorry, I updated and inserted my python code. I am using pyqt4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, in resize(), [The size is adjusted if it lies outside the range defined by minimumSize() and maximumSize()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop).

It seems that you want a fixed size for your application. You can use (in the constructor):

```
self.setFixedSize(1450,250)
```

which basically "Sets both the minimum and maximum sizes of the widget"

I would suggest to set both geometry and size in **main**:

```
programwindow.setGeometry(3,30,800,800)
programwindow.setFixedSize(1450,250)
```

---